# Each event runs on a new thread?

Tags: multithreading, node.js

I read an article an it said each callback function runs in a new thread. Is it right ?
I confused a bit. Loot at this code:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log('Connecting Connection Connected')
    socker.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1234, '127.0.0.1')
```

Each client is handled on a new thread ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Each node.js process is single-threaded and event-driven. The callback is run through an event-loop.

Comment: @BenFortune Tnx for your comment. child_process runs on new thread also ? or not ?

Comment: `child_process` creates a child process in the OS. That process executes independently and asynchronously from the parent node process.

Comment: Please someone write these comments and I will accept as default answer.